# related field nested lookup error

Tags: django, orm, foreign-keys, lookup

I have the following models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)# User can have more than one profile

class Order(models.Model):
    ship_to = models.ForeignKey(Profile)

class Shipping(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)# one order can have more than one shipping
    shipping_company = models.ForeignKey(Shipping_company)


class Shipping_company(models.Model):
    name = ...
```

So now i have the following structure:

```
User > Receiver > Order > Shipping > Shipping_company
```

**The question is:** How can i get all User models, who ordered with specific Shipping company?

If i make a query like this

```
User.objects.filter(receiver__order__shipping__shipping_company__pk=1)
```

i get

> FieldError: Relation fields do not support nested lookups

if i make something like this

```
sh_comp = items.objects.get(pk=1) # __unicode__ returns "FedEx"
User.objects.filter(receiver__order__shipping__shipping_company=sh_comp)
```

the result is

> ValueError: Cannot query "FedEx": Must be "Receiver" instance.

This seemed to be a simple and trivial task, but i can't make it work.

Comment: Since an item only exists within one shipping (order, profile) only one user ever ordered the specific item.

Comment: Have you tried making your query like this: User.objects.filter(order__shipping__item__pk=1)?

Comment: @Sayse, the question was incorrect, i reversed one relation, so now you can get multiple users for one item

Comment: @CarlosParra, this results in `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'order' into field.` because User model does not directly have _order_ field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that can be taken is as following(**I am only considering the four models you have presented in your question**),

You have foreign key of Shipping company in Shipping model. So you can make use of model function here on Shipping_company model.

Take a look at this model function

```
class Shipping_company(models.Model):

   fields... 

   def get_profiles(self):
       shippings = Shipping.objects.filter(shipping_company=self)
       users = list(set([x.order.ship_to for x in shippings]))
```

**Explanation:**

```
shippings = Shipping.objects.filter(shipping_company=self)
```

will return all the shippings for one Shipping company(FedEx in your case). Further loop through the shippings to get **ship_to** from **order** field.

**PS:** You can take it as reference and design your own solution.

**Walkthrough:**

Lets say there is shipping company 'FedEx'. So we do,

```
fedex = Shipping_company.objects.get(name='FedEx')
```

Now, when you call get_profiles on `fedex`, like

```
fedex.get_profiles()
```

what will happen is this.

fedex instance refers to self in get_profiles() function now.
Using self(fedex), we filter out **shippings** by fedex.
Then we loop through those **shippings** to get **order** per shipping and each of that order has a **ship_to(profile)** foreign key.

I guess, you are getting confused because of the **return** statement.

In elaborate fashion the whole function will look something like this

```
def get_profiles(self):
    users = list()
    shippings = Shipping.objects.filter(shipping_company=self)
    for shipping in shippings:
        order = shipping.order
        #Now you have an order per shipping, so you do
        if not order.ship_to in users:
            users.append(order.ship_to)
    return users
```

Comment: Do you propose to make a request for each shipping in list? This sounds very resource-consuming. Why it can't be done in a one simple lookup request? I know how to do it in raw SQL, but i feel like there is a good django way of doing this.

Comment: Not per shipping, its per shipping company.

Comment: i don't get it. So i got all shippings of given shipping company. How can i then use it to get a list of Users?

Comment: @George I have updated answer take a look at walkthrough and try the code once you will get an idea of what its doing.